# How can I put a 4x4 2d array inside a column in c++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How can I put a 4x4 2d array aside a column in c++?

Desired output:

```
             1995 1996 1997 1998 
John          74   45   13   57
Mark          16   12   48   75
Wilhelm       90   64   12   45
Mikhail       35   12   90   95
```

Keeping in mind that

```
 74   45   13   57  
 16   12   48   75
 90   64   12   45
 35   12   90   95
```

is a 4x4 matrix.

The problem is that I can't set the names column aside the printed matrix, nor can I declare the names as I did with the matrix numbers.

Current code:

```
int matrix[4][4] = {{ 74 , 45 , 13 , 57 },
            { 16 , 12 , 48 , 75 },
            { 90 , 64 , 12 , 45 },
            { 35 , 12 , 90 , 95 }};

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {   
        for ( int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for ( int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                cout << "\t";
                cout << matrix[x][y];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please fix the indentation and why is there a `while(true)` ?

Comment: Where is the names coming from?

Comment: Looks like you want something like a `std::map<std::string,std:map<int,int>>`.

Comment: @tobi already fixed the indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this question the answer is DONT. Create a SEPERATE array for the column headers and row headers.

The other alternative would be to create a different data structure entirely.

i.e.

```
std::string col_headers[4] = { "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998" };
std::string row_headers[4] = { "John" , "Mark", "Wilhelm", "Mikhail" };
```

now just refer to this in your original code

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {   

        for ( int c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
        {
            cout << "\t" << col_headers[c];
        }
        cout << "\n";

        for ( int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            cout << row_headers[x];
            for ( int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                cout << "\t";
                cout << matrix[x][y];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a std::map to help manage this for you:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> table =
{
  {"",        {1995, 1996, 1997, 1998}},
  {"John",    {74,   45,   13,   57  }},
  {"Mark",    {16,   12,   48,   75  }},
  {"Wilhelm", {90,   64,   12,   45  }},
  {"Mikhail", {35,   12,   90,   95  }}
};
```

Then, in your code:

```
for(auto iter : table)
{
  std::cout << iter.first;
  for(int number : iter.second)
  {
    std::cout << '\t' << number;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note: You may have to do some other formatting to make sure the spaces after the names allow the beginning of the numbers to all line up.

Comment: @flatmouse Thanks, fixed. I always get flipped around when working with maps in this kind of scenario...

Comment: An elegant solution. I like the way the `map` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

using a vector inside a vector will work. Also known as multidimensional vector allows you to create a 2d vector.

```
vector< vector<data> > vec;
```

what this will do is it will insert a  vector data inside the first position of the main vector.

So, v[0] = data inside v1

if you want to access the exact position of the 2d array then v[0][1] will return 45 and so on